# Have Python script read a text file instead of single input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I am working with this python script: https://github.com/sarchar/addressgen/blob/master/genaddress.py

Currently it works via command line like so:

```
python3 genaddress.py -p passphrase
```

How would I alter the script to accept a text file of passphrases?

Comment: Please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- not your entire script!

Comment: I feel like your question is too broad for SO. However, you could try to contact the author by filing an issue directly on GitHub, requesting the new feature.

Comment: Implement another command line argument like `-f filepath` in additon to `-p passphrase`. Then read that argument, check whether file/filepath exists and read its contents. Depending on your further passphase handling, you might want to iterate through all phrases read from the file and pass each phrase to the handler function.

Comment: As an alternative, if you _don't_ want to modify the script, you can mess around with pipes to redirect the input from a file into the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this might not directly answer the question (*How would I alter the script*), but it should achieve a similar result on bash with the following command, assuming each passphrase has its own unique output:

```
cat passphrases.txt | xargs -I phrase python3 genaddress.py -p phrase
```

This iterates through each line in `passphrases.txt` and then subsequently passes it to your script, one line at a time.